# Find the equation of the circle containing the point $(-2,2)$ and passing through..

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the circle containing the point $(-2,2)$ and passing through the points of intersection of the two circles $C_1:\; x^2+y^2+3x-2y-4=0$ and  $C_2: x^2+y^2-2x-y-6=0$

In my attempt to solve this question, I tried solving the equation simultaneously. But the results don't seems like something I can work with $(x,y)=\{0.215, 3.075\} \{-0.715, -1.575\}$

Does anyone suggest I move on with these figures? Or. Is this a wrong start?

Comment: I arrived at those figures above by doing absolutely just that... @TheSimpliFire

Comment: Do you know how to find the equation of a circle given three points on it?

Comment: @amd Yes. But my question is this:Can we say that a point that lies on circle is contained by that circle??

Comment: Please give as much [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) as possible, as it is unclear what sort of figures you want or how others can help you. What thing are you working with? In what field are you trying to solve this question?

Comment: That’s the only reasonable way to interpret this question. If you read it as saying that the point is in the interior, then there’s an infinite number of solutions, so you can’t speak of _the_ circle.

Comment: A point $(x,y)$ is contained by the circle $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2)=r^2 $ if $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2)-r^2\leq 0$ @Toby Mak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now have three noncolinear points that lie on the circle. I expect that you’ve learned how to find an equation for this circle from their coordinates. One can write the equation directly in the form of a determinant: $$\begin{vmatrix}x^2+y^2&x&y&1\\x_1^2+y_1^2&x_1&y_1&1\\x_2^2+y_2^2&x_2&y_2&1\\x_3^2+y_3^2&x_3&y_3&1\end{vmatrix} = 0.$$ Plug in the coordinates of the three points, expand the determinant, and simplify.

However, you can find the equation of the circle without computing the intersection points explicitly. Every circle that passes through those points has an equation that’s an affine combination of the two given equations: $$(1-\lambda)(x^2+y^2+3x-2y-4)+\lambda(x^2+y^2-2x-y-6)=0.$$ You can plug in the coordinates $(-2,2)$ and solve for $\lambda$, or use *Plücker’s mu* to obtain an equation directly: Given the intersection $S$ of the solution sets of $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$, and a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ not in $S$, an equation with a solution set that contains both $S$ and $P$ is $f(x_0,y_0)g(x,y)-g(x_0,y_0)f(x,y)=0$. Applying this to the two circles, we get $$-6(x^2+y^2-2x-y-6)-4(x^2+y^2+3x-2y-4) = 0,$$ which I’ll leave to you to simplify.

Comment: Yeah. This is more like it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

- equation of a circle is of the form $$x^2+y^2+ax+by+c=0\implies xa+yb+c=-x^2-y^2$$
- known points $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$, $(x_3,y_3)$ give $$\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-x_1^2-y_1^2\\-x_2^2-y_2^2\\-x_3^2-y_3^2\end{bmatrix}\implies\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1&y_1&1\\x_2&y_2&1\\x_3&y_3&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}-x_1^2-y_1^2\\-x_2^2-y_2^2\\-x_3^2-y_3^2\end{bmatrix}$$

> $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\frac{\begin{bmatrix}y_2-y_3&y_3-y_1&y_1-y_2\\x_3-x_2&x_1-x_3&x_2-x_1\\x_2y_3-x_3y_2&x_3y_1-x_1y_3&x_1y_2-x_2y_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-x_1^2-y_1^2\\-x_2^2-y_2^2\\-x_3^2-y_3^2\end{bmatrix}}{x_1(y_2-y_3)-y_1(x_2-x_3)+x_2y_3-x_3y_2}$$